# Flatten a Directory then delete the empty folders

Tags: windows, command-line

Hello I'm trying to write a command to flatten a directory of shows (Library>Show>Season>Episode) to be just (Library>episodes)

I have this right now and it works if I type it manually in CMB, But if I save it as a .cmd and double click it it doesn't seem to do anything. Am I doing something wrong? I would like it as a .cmd so I can have Task Scheduler do this on a regular basis

```
F:
cd F:\Downloads\TDARR Shows
for /r %f in (*) do @move "%f" .
for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%d"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a batch script you have to use double percent characters for variables like `%f`.

In your `.cmd` script, try

```
F:
cd "F:\Downloads\TDARR Shows"
for /r %%f in (*) do @move "%%f" .
for /f "delims=" %%d in ('dir /s /b /ad ^| sort /r') do rd "%%d"
```

**Edit:** I added quotes around the directory name containing a space in the `cd`command, although this specific command seems to work without quotes.

Comment: the space in that directory name will cause an issue. I urge the op to remove it before proceeding. at least the cd command needs the path in quotes.

Comment: @FrankThomas You are right that the directory name with a space should be quoted, but I just tested that a script `foo.cmd` containing `cd \Program Files` without quotes works on a Windows 10 system.

Comment: This new script works! Thanks

I also changed the Directory name like above per Frank Thomas's suggestion. 

TDARR_Shows

Comment: `at least the cd command needs the path in quotes. ` .. @FrankThomas , no, it doesn't.  The CD command is one of the only commands that does not require a quoted path. `CHDIR command does not treat spaces as delimiters, so it is possible to
CD into a subdirectory name that contains a space without surrounding
the name with quotes.`

Comment: Nice, thanks for the tip. I've gotten (perhaps overly) gun-shy about spaces in paths. Cheers!